# Linked sub-report loops 10x

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I have made a report based on four linked sub-reports.

All four reports work as desired as stand alone reports.

The linked report that contains the most data and charts loops 10x all the other sub-reports are present only once!

I have the sub-reports in

GH1a
GH1b
GH2
RF

The offending sub-report is in GH2

Thanks

Comment: by "loops" do you mean the subreport appears 10x in the main report?

Comment: Yes, and to clarify all sub-reports are using the same excel sheet.

Comment: I got a great explanation and fix for this here

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=19345&PN=1